# Why this ImportError is coming

Tags: python

I have installed the "**openpyxl**" library using **pip**, but still it is giving error like this as shown below:

```
ImportError: No module named openpyxl.reader.excel
```

I'm trying to import like this:

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
```

I have checked my directory structure of site-packages.It is like this now:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py
```

Is anything wrong in the directory structure may be !!!

Further I'm sure that this module is successfully installed on my machine.Since when I'm doing a **help('modules')**, there the '**openpyxl**' is getting listed.

Comment: Are you sure that you spelled openpyxl.reader.excel right?

Comment: Yes,I'm sure the name is right.Here is the link : https://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/

Comment: What is `sys.path`? I take it it lists `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`? And is there an `__init__.py` file in the `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

instead of

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if I use only openpyxl.The error still comes as: "No module named openpyxl"

Comment: which means that the installation is not complete.

Comment: I'm sure that this module is successfully installed on my machine.Since when I'm doing a **help('modules')**, there the '**openpyxl**' is getting listed